# How to change formatting setting for the collapsed block code in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, formatting, visual-studio-code

I want to change formating setting when collapsing a code block in VS Code.

Instead

[image]

```
function fillContent() { ... 
}
```

Do like this

```
function fillContent() { ... }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's not exactly what you asked for, but it is close.

Install "Explicit Folding" extension, and add this lines to settings (in the .json file of your preferred language):

```
"folding": {
    "*": {
        "begin": "{",
        "end": "}"
    }
}
```

Where `*` could be any specific language. It will collapse and fold all the text except from the first curly bracket. The result will be:

```
void Foo() {...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at present, but it is highly requested and under active discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3352

Note that the Explicit Folding extension mentioned in another answer is a dangerous workaround -- it has known issues depending on what language you're using. It may be fine for your use case, but it's worth reading the linked thread as well as the issues in the Explicit Folding repository before using it.

For now, you can lend your voice or contribute at the linked GitHub issue.

Comment: A simple formatting function causes so much discussion about its need and several years without implementation... My new voice won't help